# Дублирует текст JSOUP при парсинге HTML страницы

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Здравствуйте. Пишу учебную программу, которая будет с определенных сайтов находить все фото и скачивать их. При написании программы столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Функция при записи ссылок на фото в файл дублирует его два раза. Каждая ссылка на фото пишется два раза. Почему, не пойму. Опыта еще мало.

```
  private static void saveLinksToImage(String[] links, String className) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("linksToImage.txt");
    PrintWriter linkWriter = new PrintWriter(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(links[i]).get();
        org.jsoup.select.Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass(className);

            linkWriter.println(elements);
            linkWriter.flush();

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуй убрать linkWriter.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, метод saveLinksToImage вызывается с повторяющимися параметрами, в данном случае на вход **String[] links** передаёте 2 раза один и тотже URL.
Также неплохо было бы обернуть это в try{} для освобождения ресурса, в который пишите:

```
try (PrintWriter linkWriter = new PrintWriter(file);) {
    for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(links[i]).get();
        org.jsoup.select.Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass(className);

        linkWriter.println(elements);
        linkWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

Также проверьте, что используете последнюю версию библиотеки jsoup:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```